# ui:inputCheckbox how to allign with the checkbox itself

Tags: lightning-aura-components, checkbox

i tried to add a checkbox using ui:inputCheckbox and i wasn't able to align the checkbox with the label

this is the code:

```
<ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="leadsCheckBox" label="leads" click="{!c.handleFilters}" value="true"/>
```

and in the web app i see

[image]

please assist,
thanks

Comment: This is a matter of modifying the styling applied to your markup. Take a look into [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/) for some tips on Salesforces Lightning Design System and if you have any free time turn over to the [Lightning Components](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics) Trailhead.

Comment: @TSmith i already looked at the SLDS, copied the code from there as an example and it worked, but i want to try and use the ui:inputCheckbox. so i think its better to stick to the SLDS like you said, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer!
I wrote a class in css called `.myCheckbox`:

```
.THIS .myCheckbox{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

and added the class to the `inputCheckbox`:

```
<ui:inputCheckbox class="myCheckbox" aura:id="checkboxLeads" label="Leads" change="{!c.doInit}" value="True"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<p>` tag or even a `<div>` to display the label separately.

```
<div>leads</div>
<ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="leadsCheckBox"  click="{!c.handleFilters}" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used standard SLDS classes to achieve it :

```
  <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" labelClass="slds-p-horizontal--small slds-float--left" label="My Check" change="{!c.onCheck}"/>
```

Comment: "i did it like this" does not provide an explanation, mind further elaborating on the classes you used alongisde any docuemtnation link(s)? thanks

Comment: the css classes I used are standard SLDS classes. This code line will show the checkboxes in one line with the label as asked.

Comment: Please edit your post and explain, some users are not aware of this

Comment: I am trying to use the standard SLDS classes to get the checkbox label to line up with the checkbox.  I am not having success.  Below is my code:

Comment: $A.createComponent(

                    "ui:inputCheckbox",
                    { 
                        "value" : component.getReference("v.EventRSVP."+ fieldAPIName),
                        "aura:id": "checkbox",
                        "label": fieldLabel,
                        "labelClass":"slds-p-horizontal--small slds-float--left"
                    }

Comment: @MicheleKleinhomer - you will need to set the labelClass with attribute parameters in order to inject them in $A.createComponent..  eg. labelClass="{!v.classString}" and then populate classString with those SLDS classes