# Displaying Checkbox right side of the label

Tags: css, slds

I'am very new to slds.I have used Lightning input type tag for displaying the checkbox.Now checkbox is Appearing in left side.

Present Image:

[image]

```
  <lightning:input type="checkbox"  label="Selected :"  value="{!v.displayComparison.Selected__c}" />
```

Requirement:

But I need to display checkbox in right side of the label:

[image]

Tried code:
I have tried this link:  [Is this possible to position label for inputCheckbox on the right hand side?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180775/is-this-possible-to-position-label-for-inputcheckbox-on-the-right-hand-side)

```
   <lightning:input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" label="Checkbox label" />
```

css:

```
     .THIS .myCheckbox{
       display: inline-block;
     float: left;
   }
```

Image:
      [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this possible to position label for inputCheckbox on the right hand side?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/180775/is-this-possible-to-position-label-for-inputcheckbox-on-the-right-hand-side)

Comment: I have tried that code already.still its appearing left side

Comment: I have tried that Link already.It was appearing left side only.I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also new to SLDS but I have tried below code with some extra div tag to achieve the same.

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-13 slds-p-right_x-small">
            <p>Selected</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-12">
            <lightning:input type="checkbox" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

below is how this will look like:

[image]

Please correct me if this is not what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the standard label through the `variant` attribute:

```
<lightning:input type="checkbox" variant="label-hidden" ...
```

and add the label text separately.

Though if you want the clicks of the label to change the checkbox you will have to figure out a way to set the `for` attribute of the `label` element.