# Displaying checkbox after the field name while using lightning:inputfield

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-inputfield

Need a small help in displaying the checkbox after the field name while using lightning:inputfield

```
 <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editForm" recordId="5000D0000024fvcQAA" objectApiName="Case">

        <fieldset class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_compound">
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <div class="slds-form-element__row">
                    <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Files_with_explanation_attached__c"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                <lightning:inputField fieldName="customer_date__c"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Output :
[image]

We saw that the checkbox is displayed first and then the field name, Files_with_explanation_attached__c is a checkbox here
Can we have the fieldname and then the checkbox to be displayed as how it looks in normal layout in LEX?

We need Like this :

[image]

Comment: Here is the one of the answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/229399/displaying-checkbox-right-side-of-the-label/229403

Comment: You need to add label separately

Comment: The only issue I am seeing with the help text icon , it is coming with the checkbox. How do i remove that ?

Comment: And I cant do .slds-button__icon to display none because it removes for all . With adding label separately the help text needs to be arranged as well

Answer (score -1):

Add this line `density="compact"`, it should be like this:

```
 <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="editForm" recordId="5000D0000024fvcQAA" objectApiName="Case" density="compact">
```